# APK installation from Android studio 3 to Samsung with Android 9 gets stuck

Tags: android-studio, samsung-mobile, debian-stretch

I'm using Android Studio 3.4 on Linux Debian 9 x64 and phone Samsung SM-A10 with Android 9 Pie.
Phone is completely new and clean with latest security patch.

Every time I'm installing apk directly from Android Studio to the phone, I have to re-plug USB cable, otherwise installation stucks with "Installing..." message in status bar of the Studio. No any error messages.

What is weird - my other phones with Android 7, 8 works well - Android Studio installs the same project well, every time I click "Run" icon.

But with Samsung A10 (Android 9), the situation always looks like:

1. The phone connected with a USB cable
2. I click the "Run" icon in the Studio
3. Installation gets stuck with "Install..." status
4. I re-plug USB cable and click "Run" again.
5. Apk installs well.

...

1. I click "Run" again (does not matter if the previous app removed from the phone or not)
2. Installation gets stuck
3. I have to re-plug cable again

Also, when I download big (>100mb) file from this phone (with "adb pull ...") it gets stuck too and was solved with cable reconnect for few attempts.

What I've tried:

- reboot phone
- reboot PC
- re-enable USB debugging in Android developer menu
- enable "Instant Run" (usually I'm not using it)
- run other apps
- run debugging in Android Studio - does not start at all, gets stuck on different steps (loading some library, mostly); No error messages too

Comment: When You open Task Manager - how many adb.exe processes do You have?

Comment: When You call `adb version` in terminal - what is the output?

Comment: Do You have all up to date in Android Studio (Help > Check for updates...)?

Comment: @deadfish  - Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.36; Revision 1:7.0.0+r33-1;    


Android Studio 3.4.1 version is available, I will update now.  

"how many adb.exe processes"

Before project is opened - 0

Or you mean when I'm trying to install apk?

Comment: Yes, when you are trying to install. Maybe there are few adb.exe and they have conflict.